# How to have overflow:auto take up entire vertical height?

Tags: html, css

I have html where I have a div:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;height:100%;">
Lots of lorep ipsum here that requires scrolling.
</div>
```

My problem is when I set height to be 100%, there is no scrollbars, content runs beyond the total height of the window. If I set it to 500px, then there are scrollbars. If I set a background color when height is 100%, the whole height is colored correctly.

I want to be able to do something where I can set my height to 100% and be able to have a scrollbar that runs down to the length of the window. This div is within a div that is positioned absolutely with a height of 100%.

Comment: Are you setting the height of the element that contains it?

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle..?

Comment: I can't recreate problem, too: http://jsfiddle.net/sabrcr7k/ if your description is correct.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with the code you have posted

```
<div style="overflow:auto;height:100%;">
Lots of lorep ipsum here that requires scrolling.
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1e1gmvwp/

You will have to give a bit more context if you want an answer.

P.S. I would have commented this but you need 50 rep to write comments now

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow` property specifies whether to clip content, render scrollbars or just display content when it overflows it's block level container. It will not display the scrollbar by default if you set your container to the height of 100%.

> I want to be able to do something where I can set my height to 100% and be able to have a scrollbar that runs down to the length of the window.

You can use `overflow: scroll;`, to have the browser display scrollbars, whether or not any content is clipped.